# Power Bi UpdateDatasourceWithHttpMessagesAsync Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi

I'm trying to update the dataset credentials in power bi using the method UpdateDatasourceWithHttpMessagesAsync. but I'm facing g the issue **Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'**. I have added the below permission in Azure API. Please help.

[image]

```
public static HttpStatusCode UpdateCredentials(string datasetId, string reportId, string userName, string password, string workspaceId)
    {
        var tokenCredentials = GetTokenCredentials();

        var updateDatasourceRequest = new UpdateDatasourceRequest()
        {
            CredentialDetails = new CredentialDetails()
            {
                Credentials = "{\'credentialData\':[{\'name\':\'username\', \'value\':\' " + userName + "\'},{\'name\':\'password\', \'value\':\'" + password + "\'}]}",
                CredentialType = "Basic",
                EncryptedConnection = "Encrypted",
                EncryptionAlgorithm = "None",
                PrivacyLevel = "None"
            }
        };

        string restUrlDatasetToUpdate = ApiUrl + "v1.0/myorg/datasets/" + datasetId + "/";
        string restUrlDatasetDefaultGateway = restUrlDatasetToUpdate + "Default.GetBoundGatewayDataSources";
        string jsonDefaultGateway = ExecuteGetRequest(restUrlDatasetDefaultGateway, tokenCredentials.Item2);
        Gateway defaultGateway = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GatewayCollection>(jsonDefaultGateway)).value[0];
        string restUrlPatchCredentials = ApiUrl + "v1.0/myorg/" + "gateways/" + defaultGateway.gatewayId + "/" + "datasources/" + defaultGateway.id + "/";
        DataSourceCredentials dataSourceCredentials =
        new DataSourceCredentials
        {
            credentialType = "Basic",
            basicCredentials = new BasicCredentials
            {
                Username = userName,
                Password = password
            }
        }; 
        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials.Item1))
        {
            var res = client.Gateways.UpdateDatasourceWithHttpMessagesAsync(defaultGateway.gatewayId, defaultGateway.id, updateDatasourceRequest).Result;//facing issue here                
            return res.Response.StatusCode;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I guess you are authenticating with [Service Principal](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/use-power-bi-api-with-service-principal-preview/). In this case the API permissions are irrelevant. Check the rights of the SP on the workspace instead.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I have enabled service principal settings, still facing the same issue